# jenkins LDAP authentication - deny

Tags: authentication, jenkins, ldap

We use Jenkins with LDAP authentication. My question: is it possible to implement this rights scenario?

```
if not logged-in (anonymous)                      ==> read all                           
if logged in (via LDAP) but not a "special" user  ==> full access to specified jobs only 
if logged in (via LDAP) and also a "special" user ==> full admin access
```

My goal is to avoid having to manage large numbers of users explicitly.

There's a plugin "Role Strategy Plugin" that supports permissions for specified jobs, but it doesn't distinguish between anonymous and logged-in (via LDAP) users. It seems that the only way to grant access to specified jobs is to grant it user by user...which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Active Directory? If so:

- you can use groups for authentication, and therefore assign rights to the entire group.
- you can use a project-based matrix, so specified jobs will only be visible to specific groups

If you cannot (only LDAP):

I think you can still do the above, but I think your LDAP configuration will require more work for groups. I am not sure of group support in the Jenkins LDAP API.

Comment: The project-based matrix works with LDAP as well, and @mml_sw could set up LDAP groups containing all the "special" users and all the non-special users to avoid having to set permissions user by user.  However, he'd have to go in and add the LDAP group to the permissions for each job that regular authenticated users should have full access to.  This is possible to automate with some scripting; please post a comment if you'd like details.